# Non standard code, or g++ error?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Okay I've developed some code;

[Linkage](http://liveworkspace.org/code/NhL3i%240) (it's rather long)

And when I compile it with Clang++ 3.2, it runs and results in;

```
stdout: 
print: C-3PO
print: R2D2
```

However if I try to compile it with G++ 4.7.2, I get these errors;

```
Compilation finished with errors:
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:90:71: error: no matching function for call to 'makeRunnable(int (&)(char, int, const char*), char, int)'
source.cpp:90:71: note: candidate is:
source.cpp:74:27: note: template<class ... RUN_TIME, class T, class ... CONSTRUCTION_TIME> Runnable<T, RUN_TIME ...>* makeRunnable(T (*)(CONSTRUCTION_TIME ..., RUN_TIME ...), CONSTRUCTION_TIME ...)
source.cpp:74:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
source.cpp:90:71: note:   mismatched types 'const char*' and 'char'
source.cpp:90:71: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '<expression error>'
source.cpp:92:72: error: no matching function for call to 'makeRunnable(int (&)(char, int, const char*), char)'
source.cpp:92:72: note: candidate is:
source.cpp:74:27: note: template<class ... RUN_TIME, class T, class ... CONSTRUCTION_TIME> Runnable<T, RUN_TIME ...>* makeRunnable(T (*)(CONSTRUCTION_TIME ..., RUN_TIME ...), CONSTRUCTION_TIME ...)
source.cpp:74:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
source.cpp:92:72: note:   mismatched types 'int' and 'char'
source.cpp:92:72: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '<expression error>'
```

And almost the same with G++ 4.8.0 (although prettier formatted).

So the question is;

Is this code standard conformant? - If not why?

**Edit** Relevant code from link:

```
template<typename... RUN_TIME, typename T, typename... CONSTRUCTION_TIME> 
Runnable<T, RUN_TIME...>* makeRunnable(T (*FunctionType)(CONSTRUCTION_TIME..., RUN_TIME...), CONSTRUCTION_TIME... ct_args)  // Line 74
{
    return new FunctionDelegate<T,
                                std::tuple<CONSTRUCTION_TIME...>,
                                std::tuple<CONSTRUCTION_TIME..., RUN_TIME...>,
                                RUN_TIME...>(FunctionType, std::make_tuple(ct_args...));
}

int print_function(char arg1, int arg2, const char* arg3)
{
    std::cout << "print: " << arg1 << arg2 << arg3 << std::endl;
    return 2;
}

int main()
{   
    auto function1 = makeRunnable<const char*>(print_function, 'C', -3);  // Line 90
    int n = function1->invoke("PO");
    auto function2 = makeRunnable<int, const char*>(print_function, 'R');  // Line 92
    function2->invoke(n, "D2");
}
```

The point of this question, isn't really the implementation in question, more that Clang++ and G++ is not disagreeing on whether this is an error or not.

Comment: Any chance you could break this down a little to isolate the issue rather than having us look through that chunk of code?

Comment: @us2012; I've made it a bit smaller now.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? Which template arguments are meant to be passed explicitly and which are supposed to be deduced?

Comment: @AndyProwl: The purpose of the function is to create an object (holding a function pointer), that can be invoked, at some later time in the program, however with some arguments given at creation time, and the rest at calltime.

Comment: So you are kind of reimplementing [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, kinda, I'm trying to learn using tuples and variadic templates.

Comment: @AndyProwl: The RUN_TIME... is supposed to be passed explicitly, and the rest deduced.

Comment: “Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.” –Brian Kernighan

Comment: What you really need is a compiler that understands the binary language of moisture vaporators.

Comment: @Kieveli: Instead one should write stupid code I take it? - atleast one can debug it easily then?

Comment: @Skeen: Code can be written to perform a single task in an infinite number of ways. What matters most is how easy it is for someone else to read and understand what you did.  What matters most is how easy it is for you to understand it after 10 months of working on other projects.

Comment: @Kieveli: I agree with that, however I dont see how the above task could be done any simpler, the alternative to a single variadic template concatenation (and having the compiler do the hard work) is to manually calculate the suffix of one variadic template, given two overlapping variadic templates, I clearly dont see how thats easier to understand, as thats about 50 lines of tuple folding? (versus 1 line). The point of the post was whether I could go with the clean 1 line solution (that is whether it's standard conformant).

Comment: Also the issue is has nothing to do with debugging, it has to do with standard conformance, in orde to ensure that the code is clear and understandable. Also as I was able to develop a workaround, then by definition I must be twice as smart as I thought?

Comment: Btw, if you have a easier way to do this, please let me know, I'd love to reduce the complexity if possible, I just dont see how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played with the code a bit, it seems that g++ can't handle the deducing of variadic template concatenation (between the `|!|`).

```
Runnable<T, RUN_TIME...>* makeRunnable(T (*FunctionType)|!|(CONSTRUCTION_TIME..., RUN_TIME...)|!|, CONSTRUCTION_TIME... ct_args)
```

And the code is fixable, by adding another variadic template argument, such that g++ can deduce the template directly.