# Deducing variadic template concatenation

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

So the question is simple, should the compiler be able to deduce template concatenation, according to the standard?

Example:

```
template<typename... RUN_TIME, typename T, typename... CONSTRUCTION_TIME> 
Runnable<T, RUN_TIME...>* makeRunnable(T (*FunctionType)(CONSTRUCTION_TIME..., RUN_TIME...), CONSTRUCTION_TIME... ct_args)
{
    ...
}

int print_function(char arg1, int arg2, const char* arg3);

makeRunnable<const char*>(print_function, 'C', -3);
```

Should the compile be able to figure that the function `print_function` is alright to pass, given the arguments and explicit template?

See more; [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270998/non-standard-code-or-g-error)

Comment: I can't really make head or tail of your question, but what's wrong with std::bind?

Comment: nothing, except that I'm trying to develop my own system, and I've came across the issue.

Comment: @Ali: What do you mean by 'absorbs', and because I'd also like a small working implementation for my OS kernel.

Comment: Why would you (try to) mislead the compiler? You pass a `int(*)(char,int,char const*)` but define `T` to be `char const*` - the compiler will *not* deduce that for you, since the function poitner you pass does not fit possible signatures.

Comment: @Ali: its the opposite - at least gcc will consider `CONSTRUCTION_TIME...` to be an empty list: http://ideone.com/fxg2YG

Comment: @Ali: Clang++ compiles and runs the above example, with `RUN_TIME={const char*}`, `CONSTRUCTION_TIME={char,int}`, `T={int}`, and  `(CONSTRUCTION_TIME..., RUN_TIME...)={char,int,const char*}`, G++ on the other hand throws an error. - The question is about, whether of these is the correct behavior.

Comment: @ArneMertz: GCC shouldn't be able to consider `CONSTRUCTION_TIME...` as the empty list, as there's arguments given directly to be deduced `('C', -3)`, in `ct_args`.

Comment: The thing is, that the compiler has to concatenate these two variadic templates, and then deduce the return type from the passed argument (assuming it fits the concatenation of the two variadic templates).

Comment: @Skeen I think that's part of where the compiler starts deducing the types. If it starts at the right, it can deduce `COSTRUCTION_TIME...`. If it starts at the left, it has somehow to match to packs to one function signature and fails. However, this is a somewhat academic question since what you are trying to do obviosly lacks portability, no matter which compiler is right.

Comment: @Ali: `RUN_TIME...` also cannot be removed, as it's passed template arguments explicitly?

Comment: @ArneMertz; Why would it lack portability? - If it follows the standard, it's a compiler bug? - And the question I asked is whether this follows the standard.

Comment: Well, if it's a compiler bug, it cannot be compiled on that compiler, so the portability is decreased. `export` for templates was standard in C++03 - you would not use it, because only one compiler had implemented it and so it was not portable. Standard conformity and portability are two different things.

Comment: @Mertz: I agree, but C++11  features  \neq export, since export was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the question what the standard says about what compilers *should* be able to do, here's some TMP to make it compile on gcc:

```
/** PackDiff: 
 *  Template Metafunction to deduce the difference of two parameter packs.
 *  To distinguish two packs we have to brace them in two tuples
 */
template <class Tup1, class Tup2> struct PackDiff;

/** Basic algorithm: (T, X1...) - (T, X2...) = (X1...) - (X2...) */
template <class T, class... Pack1, class... Pack2>
struct PackDiff<std::tuple<T, Pack1...>, std::tuple<T, Pack2...>>
  : PackDiff<std::tuple<Pack1...>, std::tuple<Pack2...>> {};

/** End of recursion: (X1...) - () = (X1...) */
template <class... Pack1>
struct PackDiff<std::tuple<Pack1...>, std::tuple<>>
{
  typedef std::tuple<Pack1...> type;
};

/** Mismatch: (T, X1...) - (U, X2...) is undefined */
template <class T1, class... Pack1, class T2, class... Pack2>
struct PackDiff<std::tuple<T1, Pack1...>, std::tuple<T2, Pack2...>>
{ typedef struct PACK_MISMATCH {} type; };

/** Rest: () - (X2...) is undefined */  
template <class... Pack2>
struct PackDiff<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Pack2...>>
{ typedef struct LEFT_PACK_TOO_SHORT{} type; };



//make Runnable Type of T and a diff tuple:
template <class T, class Tup1> struct MakeRunnableType;

template <class T, class... Pack>
struct MakeRunnableType<T, std::tuple<Pack...>>
{ typedef Runnable<T, Pack...> type; };



template<typename... AllArgs, typename T, typename... SomeArgs> 
auto makeRunnable(T (*FunctionType)(AllArgs...), SomeArgs... ct_args)
  -> typename MakeRunnableType<T, 
          typename PackDiff<std::tuple<AllArgs...>, 
                std::tuple<SomeArgs...>
          >::type
     >::type*
{
  typedef typename PackDiff<std::tuple<AllArgs...>, 
                std::tuple<SomeArgs...>
          >::type PackDiff_t;
  typedef typename MakeRunnableType<T, PackDiff_t>::type ReturnType;
  return new ReturnType();
}
```

I know. Doesn't look very pretty. But [works on GCC.](http://ideone.com/ANq8kQ)

Comment: You could just add another variadic template to the makeRunnable function, and have the function pointer take this as an argument, which makes.it compile in gcc as well, but the question I wanted to know the answer to, was what the standard states about variadic template concatenation.

Comment: With a third parameter pack you'd have to specify it, since you are only passing two to the function, so only two can be deduced by the compiler. As for the standard question, I'll have a look at the standard, maybe I can figure something out.

Comment: Right! - It turns out this is actually what I've did in my code too, in order to avoid that problem.